# c# Main thread blocked while connecting to IZKEM Connect_Net blocks UI

Tags: c#, multithreading, async-await, task, zkemkeeper

I'm using zkemkeeper SDK to handle Attendance Machine and it is working fine but when I connect, it hangs form UI, so I started using Async Task to avoid this issue but it didn't work and here is my code:

```
public async Task<bool> Connect()
{
    await Task.Delay(5000);
    await Task.Run(() => ZkemClientObj.Connect_Net(ip, port));
}
```

in task delay UI was not blocked but when I start Connect_Net it blocks UI.
I tried a lot of things and it works fine but only with this snippet.

Update

This is connection button event method:

```
CZKEM ZkemClientObj = new CZKEM();

private async void MachineConnectionAction(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var isConnected = await Connect();

    if (isConnected) 
    {
        UpdateConnectionStatus();
    } 
    else 
    {
        ShowErrorMessage();
    }

}

public async Task<bool> Connect()
{
     string ip = MachineIPAddress.Text.Trim();
     int port = int.Parse(MachinePort.Text.Trim());

     return await Task.Run(() => ZkemClientObj.Connect_Net(ip, port));
}
```

Comment: Are you sure? Aren't you blocking yourself somewhere else? Can you show the code calling `Connect`?

Comment: Hello Mohammed. It's very important to clarify of how you call the Connect method. Please provide us with the code.

Comment: @PauloMorgado I updated my code

Comment: That can't be blocking the UI thread. What happens if you replace `Connect()` for `Task.Run(() => Thread.Sleep(10000))` in `MachineConnectionAction`

Comment: I did that and UI was not blocked, it was fine, that's why I'm concern when it comes to connecting to machine UI blocked

Answer (score 0):

Try this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskfactory.startnew?view=netframework-4.8

```
 public async Task Connect()
   {
        await Task.Delay(5000);
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ZkemClientObj.Connect_Net(ip, port));
   }
```

Comment: It doesn't work, I needed to add await before like this:
`await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ZkemClientObj.Connect_Net(ip, port));`
and still not working, UI still blocked

Comment: Attach full code inside ZkemClientObj.Connect_Net also

Comment: It is not recommended to use `Task.Factory.StartNew` with `async-await`.